# How to pan google map when string search is done?

Tags: javascript

So here I have JavaScript code referring to  fusion table layer in Google map.
I have implemented HTML which holds search input field, and in js I have function to query fusion tables, find string and mark it on map.
I want to pan map toward searched string location.
Please how to do that?

```
function initialize() {

var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.879, -87.624),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);

var polyOptions = {
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
}

var markers = [];

poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
poly.setMap(map);
var deleteNode = function(mev) {
if (mev.vertex != null) {
   poly.getPath().removeAt(mev.vertex);
}
}
google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'rightclick', deleteNode);


google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

    var path = poly.getPath();

    path.push(event.latLng);

    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        title: '#' + path.getLength(),
        map: map
    }));

    if(path.getLength() == 4) {
        console.log('box it');
        path.push(markers[0].getPosition());
        console.dir(markers);
        layer_0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: "col3",
      from: "1xUO04Jq46-u8QaqgztZ6rCA3xETHtb2u4Zee6KTP"
    },
    map: map,
    styleId: 7,
    templateId: 44
  });
        layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  map: map,
  heatmap: { enabled: false },
  query: {
    select: "col11",
    from: "1xUO04Jq46-u8QaqgztZ6rCA3xETHtb2u4Zee6KTP",
    where: ""
  },
  options: {
    styleId: 7,
    templateId: 944
  }

});
    }


});
}

function deletepoly() {
poly.setMap(null) ;
layer.setMap(null);
path.setMap(null);

};

function changeMap_0() {
  var whereClause;
  var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string_0').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
  if (searchString != '--Select--') {
    whereClause = "'PONAME' CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '" + searchString + "'";
  }
  layer_0.setOptions({
    query: {
      select: "col11",
      from: "1xUO04Jq46-u8QaqgztZ6rCA3xETHtb2u4Zee6KTP",
      where: whereClause,

    }
  });
}   

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1siIdpr3qgyEXoeLEJYL4XDVeC8poRJjw